# How to search data from sqlite with UISearchBar in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to ask a question.
Now i am training in iOS with UISearchBar , TableView and Sqlite.
I have sqlite database and i want to search data from that sqlite database and then i want to show that search data in tableView.
I already select data into NSMutableArray named myArray in ViewDidLoad Event like following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyInfo *myInfo = [[MyInfo alloc] init];
    myArray = [myInfo getInitialData]; // myArray is my NSMutableArray's variable name and getData From getInitialData Method.

    [tableData addObjectsFromArray:myArray]; // tableData is my next NSMutableArray's variable name that i want to show search data in tableView.
}
```

like that.I added data from myArray into tableData.
and then i write some of code in UISearchBar's textDidChange Events following like that.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil)
    {
        [myTableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    NSInteger counter = 0;
    for(NSString *nameMe in myArray)
    {
        NSRange r = [[nameMe lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
            {
                [tableData addObject:nameMe];
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

But i can't search data from database.There was error occurring.
I think i am wrong in my search code.
My column name is "name" that i want to search from database.
However i don't know how to search data with UISearchBar.
If my codes are wrong,please advice me how to search data from sqlite.
I am just beginner in iOS , please help me.

Best Regards,

Comment: If there is a sample iOS project for UISearchBar with UITableView and Sqlite database, please share me!. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C11-Tables/16-Searching%20Tables) It is doing exaclty what u want to do. only u have to modify just a bit the table view in the example are filled with plist Element (correct me if i m wrong i used it long time back)

All u have to do is that fill the Array with the Values from Sqlite Database. I could have shown u that as well but i dont have my mac with me right now

Do let me know if it worked or u need any other help...!!!!

Cheeers!!!

## Updated

Did u allocated ur NSMutatableArray?

Some thing like

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I will try your help.If you can later, please teach me your code. Thanks again.